# ZBar SDK - Not exactly sure what's going on

Tags: ios, qr-code, zbar-sdk, zbar

I'm fairly new to the iOS SDK and Objective C, and I'm not exactly sure what's going on in this code snippet:

```
-(IBAction) scanButton{

    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];

    reader.readerDelegate = self;

    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner  = reader.scanner;

    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:0];

    [self presentViewController:reader animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

What exactly does the readerDelegate do? Does it just wait for an object (barcode) to be returned?

Also what is the = reader.scanner doing?

Answer (score 0):

readerDelegate is setting to be the object where are you calling this method, that means that it should implement methods of this delegate, which are responsible for getting scanned data back, in those methods you can do whatever you want with scanned data.
Also

```
 ZBarImageScanner *scanner  = reader.scanner;
```

is getting scanner object (which is parsing image to get data from it) and its setting parsing parameters here

```
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:0];
```

Your job is to read documentation what scaning parameters you want (the best would be to leave default ones. And implement delegate methods to manage data you are receiving from scanned image.